# How to display fetched image url data?

Tags: php, arrays, fetch

I'm halfway through figuring out a little project of mine, where I basically fetch a page's images, and then redisplay them on another site of mine. While I'm doing this for purposes of displaying random images of my artwork (won't waste your time explaining the details), I'll use the following example because it basically will do exactly what I'm attempting to do.

Right now what I'm able to do is fetch all image links from a given page, but I don't know how to re-display them as images on a website. Currently the data I get looks like this (test I did): http://www.wilsonschlamme.com/wiki.php

Array

```
(
[0] => https ://kfjhiakwhefkiujahefawef/awoefjoiwejfowe.jpg

[1] => https ://oawiejfoiaewjfoajfeaweoif/awoeifjao;iwejfoawiefj.png

)
```

*fyi as you can see, on the link the urls/file names are different each time. But it still successfully pulls the file names!

*in case you're curious as to where I'm pulling the img information from, it's a nice little wiki random img generator: http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:Random/File

So that's pretty cool, happy to get this far because I'm very new to PHP. But what I now need to do, is RE display the FIRST image the array picks up, which is img 0. If you're wondering why I'm going through this headache, it has to do with random images, I'm going to be dealing with them, so naturally I need the site to pick up whatever image it finds, regardless of file name.

So likewise, I'm thinking perhaps I replace the code in this current php I'm working with that is displaying this array in text format on the above test link, and instead have some code that takes [0] array, and displays that as an actual image instead, in other words pulls the image from that link, like a < img src="https://_____

How to do that exactly is where I'm lost. The desired output, is a website that shows the images from the array that is being gathered. So, this website would just be showing images, the fetched images. Literally images, not just the text.

Any thoughts? Thanks so much for reading this. -Wilson

The PHP code that's doing this:

```
<?php
/*
Credits: Bit Repository
URL: http://www.bitrepository.com/
*/

$url = 'http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:Random/File';

// Fetch page
$string = FetchPage($url);

// Regex that extracts the images (full tag)
$image_regex_src_url = '/<img[^>]*'.

'src=[\"|\'](.*)[\"|\']/Ui';

preg_match_all($image_regex, $string, $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

$img_tag_array = $out[0];

echo "<pre>"; print_r($img_tag_array); echo "</pre>";

// Regex for SRC Value
$image_regex_src_url = '/<img[^>]*'.

'src=[\"|\'](.*)[\"|\']/Ui';

preg_match_all($image_regex_src_url, $string, $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

$images_url_array = $out[1];

echo "<pre>"; print_r($images_url_array); echo "</pre>";

// Fetch Page Function

function FetchPage($path)
{
$file = fopen($path, "r"); 

if (!$file)
{
exit("The was a connection error!");
} 

$data = '';

while (!feof($file))
{
// Extract the data from the file / url

$data .= fgets($file, 1024);
}
return $data;
}




for($i=0; $i<count($arr1); $i++) {
echo '<img src="'.$arr1[$i].'">';
}

?>
```

Comment: Start by **not using regex to parse html**, use a proper html parser, like `DOMDocument`, also, your question is very unclear to me, please post **clear** sample of the **input** and desired **output**

Comment: Pedro, thanks for the thoughts. I will look into that. The desired output, is a website that shows the images from the array that is being gathered. So, this website would just be showing images, the fetched images. Literally images, not just the text

Comment: Wondering if this id won the right route:  < img src="<?=$array['image'];?>" />
 I'm not sure exactly how to get that working however.

Comment: Please post the url where you want to grab the images

Comment: Thanks. If I can crack it with this example, I can do it for my site. Note, this link sends user to random image page, in other words, the ultimate destination will be different each time. http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:Random/File

Comment: Also, if you mean the link that will re display the images. www.wilsonschlamme.com/wiki.php is the test page i've been trying to get working.

Comment: Getting error using.      <?php

    for($x=0; $x<10; $x++)
    {
    $html =file_get_contents("http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:Random/
    File");

    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $image_src =  $xpath-
    >query('//div[contains(@class,"fullImageLink")]/a/img')[0]-
    >getAttribute('src') ;
    echo "<img src='$image_src'><br>";

    }

    ?>